# I'm trying to make a music player, but I can't figure out how does the openfiledialog multiselect work

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

So I have this code:

```
            OpenFileDialog diag = new OpenFileDialog();
            diag.Filter = "wav, mp3|*.wav;*.mp3";
            diag.Multiselect = true;
            if (diag.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                label.Content = diag.FileName;
                mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(diag.FileName));
                mediaPlayer.Play();
            }
```

And what I want to do, is to select a number of songs, and make this program shuffle through them. How can I put all of these strings (diag.FileNames) into a list?

Comment: diag.FileNames is already a list..

Answer (score 0):

diag.FileNames will return the list of the selected item's names. So you can use that list to get each file name.

```
OpenFileDialog diag = new OpenFileDialog();
diag.Filter = "wav, mp3|*.wav;*.mp3";
diag.Multiselect = true;
var dialogResult = diag.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (string file in diag.FileNames) 
    {
        label.Content = file;
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(file));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```